# Spring Security + Keycloak - How to handle Ajax Requests in conjunction with "Access Token Lifespan"

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-security, primefaces, keycloak

I recently implemented Keycloak into my Primefaces Spring-Boot Web Application.
It all works great except one thing: Ajax request "timeout" after whatever is set in keycloak under "Access Token Lifespan". There is no redirect. The ajaxStatus never ends and the user is forced to reload the page. Looking at the Request, I am getting back a 401 "Unauthorized".

E.g. the user loads a site and does whatever he wants to do. After 5 minutes of time without reloading or navigation to another page, ajax requests get unauthorized.

So my question is: What are the best practices in this situation and is this even the expected behavior?

I see following options:

1. Increase the "Access Token Lifespan"
2. Intercept the ajax call and reload page if user isnt authorized anymore -> user looses possible input he made on the site
3. Refresh Access Token lifespan on every ajax call within its current lifespan -> Is that even possible?

Here is my SpringSecurity and Keycloak configuration:

```
@Configuration
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Inject
    public void setKeycloakClientRequestFactory(KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory) {
        this.keycloakClientRequestFactory = keycloakClientRequestFactory;
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(true);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(true);
        return registrationBean;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/pages/accessdenied*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/pages/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/pages/shared/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/pages/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
    }


}
```

## Keycloak settings

```
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://host:8090/auth
keycloak.realm="realm"
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.resource="client-name"
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

[image: Keycloak Client Settings]

Answer (score 0):

As the Spring Security Adapter uses web sessions, I would recommend you two steps (you'll need to implement at least the second one):

**1. Increase the KC session timeouts for the realm:**

[image]

This tells how much the session is going to last for an access (takes care of the refresh token lifespan). This values are relative to how much you want to let a user in without having to authenticate himself again.

Increasing Access Token Lifespan is not recommended since an attacker who could intercept one token would have a wider time window to perform valid actions.

**2. In your view side, control 401 exceptions**

Even you've got a long lasting session, 401 exceptions can still happen. So you need to control them in the view side. Using AngularJs, for example, a very basic way to redirect the user to the login page in case a 401 code happens might be something like this (put in some interceptor):

```
function responseError(response) {
    console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    if (!(response.status === 401)) {
        $rootScope.$emit('httpError', response);
    } else {
        //401 error
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol + '//'
                + window.location.host + '/sso/logout';
    }
    return $q.reject(response);
}
```

For Primefaces, your best might be implementing some logic in a server filter which sends a redirect to `/SSO/logout` if your business logic sends a 401 response.

Comment: Increasing the SSO Session Idle time does not help with my current problem. It is already set to 30 minutes and is exactly what I need.
Redirecting on 401s is a good hint for intercepting ajax requests. Is there a "max" value for Access Token Lifespan which one should use for not being too vulnerable to attacks? 5 Minutes is way too short for my application as I have a lot of statistics on one site which are being loaded on demand (triggering ajax request)...

Comment: The access token renewal process should be automatically handled by the Spring Security Adapter (you shouldn't get 401 in any case, in theory, if it's properly configured). So the adapter should work well either with 1 min or 5 min. It is recommended for the Access Token to be short-lived, in general. Still, if you use HTTPS for your connections nobody should be able to retrieve your token.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I have a similar problem, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800246/why-do-i-receive-401-with-spring-boot-and-keycloak-if-i-dont-use-the-app-for-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800246/why-do-i-receive-401-with-spring-boot-and-keycloak-if-i-dont-use-the-app-for-a).. But I don't need to do a login, if I just refresh the pag (F5), I can work safely with my app.. why?