# Keycloak: refresh access token after expired for ajax calls

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm facing the same problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319170/spring-security-keycloak-how-to-handle-ajax-requests-in-conjunction-with-ac) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352049/keycloak-getting-401-in-ajax-calls-after-token-expired) but they weren't answered and I have a little more information and different set up so it's not duplicated.

I have a spring boot 1.5.13 application, using spring security adapter with a keycloak 3.4.3 server. Everything is working fine but when I make an ajax request to the application after 5 minutes without reloading the page, the response returns with a 401 error. I know this is because the access token has expired.

The documentation states the following:

> **token-minimum-time-to-live**
>   Amount of time, in seconds, to preemptively refresh an active access token with the Keycloak server before it expires. This is especially useful when the access token is sent to another REST client where it could expire before being evaluated. This value should never exceed the realm’s access token lifespan. This is OPTIONAL. The default value is 0 seconds, so adapter will refresh access token just if it’s expired.

Documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#java-adapters)

I've changed the default value of the `token-minimum-time-to-live` in the keycloak.json but I does not work.

```
{
"realm": "APPS",
"auth-server-url": "http://localhost:9100/auth",
"ssl-required": "external",
"resource": "WebApp",
"public-client": true,
"confidential-port": 0,
"use-resource-role-mappings": true,
"principal-attribute":"preferred_username",
"token-minimum-time-to-live" : 15
}
```

So I think I'm missing something in the spring security adapter configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws   
Exception {

KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = 
keycloakAuthenticationProvider();

keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new 
SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Bean
ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> getHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
    .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/sso/logout")) 
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/Portal/**").hasRole("App_Access")
    .anyRequest().permitAll()                
    .and()
    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
    ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, even if you extend that time, you'll still face the problem after a longer time period.

Would be an option for you if each ajax request you create, reacts natively to those 401 by "auto-refreshing/reloading" your page? If your token still can be refreshed, it'll be automatically be refreshed by the adapter back-channel request towards the auth-server (after the page refresh); and if the token can't be refreshed because you crossed the period in which is valid to refresh a token, then your aplication will be redirected to the @auth server user-login page.

Would that help you? In this case you may want to slightly rework your page so that after it reloads the page after a 401 ajax request, then that "failed request" repeat itself automatically after the page reload (only this time the access_token will be refreshed or completely expired).

If everything works as intended, the end-user will either not notice the page reload and everything will work as usual, or he'll be redirected to the credential input page.

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

as for the "token-minimum-time-to-live" and other token configuration options, have you tried directly @Realm->settings->Tokens directly on the keycloak admin page?

I believe this other question is related to yours & offers a kind of similar solution: [Spring Security + Keycloak - How to handle Ajax Requests in conjunction with "Access Token Lifespan"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319170/spring-security-keycloak-how-to-handle-ajax-requests-in-conjunction-with-ac?noredirect=1&lq=1)